# Swap contract in cosmWASM not sending NFT to owner

Tags: cosmwasm

I am building a swap NFTs contract using cosmWASM in the SEI blockchain: you send a NFT from an old collection and it sends you back a NFT from a new collection. It is working and passing the tests but in SEI testnet I am not able to send the new NFT (it does not fail or anything but it simply does not send the new NFT). My whole testing workflow is:

1. Deploy a NFT collection (cw721)
2. Mint an NFT from that collection (e.g. token #1)
3. Deploy a new NFT collection (cw721)
4. Mint all the NFTs to the contract (it becomes the NFT owner)
5. Send the old NFT #1 to the swap contract (using the cosmos SDK and the `send_nft` function)
6. The swap contract gets the old NFT but does not anything (it should burn the old and transfer the new one to the original owner)

The function code is

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;
use cosmwasm_std::{from_json, Addr, Empty, MessageInfo, Response};
use cw721::Cw721ReceiveMsg;
use cw2981_royalties::ExecuteMsg as Cw2981ExecuteMsg;
use cw721_base::helpers::Cw721Contract;

use crate::{msg::InnerMsg, ContractError};

pub fn receive_nft(info: MessageInfo, receive_msg: Cw721ReceiveMsg) -> Result<Response, ContractError> {
    let token_id = receive_msg.token_id.as_str();
    let recipient = receive_msg.sender.as_str();
    let inner_msg: InnerMsg = from_json(&receive_msg.msg)?;
    let new_collection_addr = inner_msg.new_collection_addr;

    let old_collection_env_addr = info.sender.as_str();
    let old_collection_addr = Addr::unchecked("sei1exm3fjundhdzf6wng3xcny4nhjlawwmztxd286f35zcvx4mav4jqcnese6");
    if old_collection_addr != old_collection_env_addr {
        return Err(ContractError::Unauthorized {});
    }

    Cw721Contract::<Empty, Empty>(
        old_collection_addr.clone(),
        PhantomData,
        PhantomData
    ).call(Cw2981ExecuteMsg::Burn { token_id: token_id.to_string() }).unwrap();

    Cw721Contract::<Empty, Empty>(
        new_collection_addr.clone(),
        PhantomData,
        PhantomData
    ).call(Cw2981ExecuteMsg::TransferNft { recipient: recipient.to_string(), token_id: token_id.to_string() }).unwrap();

    let response = Response::new();
    // Return the response
    Ok(
        response
            .add_attribute("action", "burn_to_mint")
            .add_attribute("old_collection", old_collection_addr.to_string())
            .add_attribute("old_collection_env", old_collection_env_addr.to_string())
            .add_attribute("new_collection", new_collection_addr.to_string())
            .add_attribute("recipient", recipient.to_string())
            .add_attribute("token_id", token_id.to_string())
    )
}
```

The original repository is [here](https://github.com/NicoSerranoP/swap-nft-template)

I was expecting these two functions to execute: burn the old NFT and send the new one to the owner.

```
Cw721Contract::<Empty, Empty>(
        old_collection_addr.clone(),
        PhantomData,
        PhantomData
    ).call(Cw2981ExecuteMsg::Burn { token_id: token_id.to_string() }).unwrap();

    Cw721Contract::<Empty, Empty>(
        new_collection_addr.clone(),
        PhantomData,
        PhantomData
    ).call(Cw2981ExecuteMsg::TransferNft { recipient: recipient.to_string(), token_id: token_id.to_string() }).unwrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding the callbacks to the response object:

```rust
// ...

let burn_callback = Cw721Contract::<Empty, Empty>(
        old_collection_addr.clone(),
        PhantomData,
        PhantomData
    ).call(burn_msg)?;

    let mint_msg: cw721_base::ExecuteMsg<Empty, Empty> = Cw721ExecuteMsg::TransferNft {
        recipient: recipient.to_string(),
        token_id: token_id.to_string() as String
    };
    let mint_callback = Cw721Contract::<Empty, Empty>(
        new_collection_addr.clone(),
        PhantomData,
        PhantomData
    ).call(mint_msg)?;

    let response = Response::new();
    // Return the response
    Ok(
        response
            .add_message(burn_callback)
            .add_message(mint_callback)

//...
```